# SQL Query to convert cron expression to date/time format

Tags: sql, oracle, cron

I have some cron jobs scheduled on a Linux host.
Each job writes execution log in an Oracle database table. The table has a result column that can be valued with 'OK' or 'KO'. The table also has a timestamp column that is valued with the last execution time for the job. 
In this way I'm sure about the job result.
Now I need to be sure that the job has actually ran.
I have another table with job ID and cron expression, for example:

```
JOB_ID        SCHEDULE
102           00 09 * * *
```

How can I write a sql select to check the last execution time against the SCHEDULE field (cron expression)?

I will appreciate any suggestion, I can change the my approach but I would like to use the cron syntax inside the database table

Regards
Giova

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Sentinel : I’m using Oracle

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `regexp_substr` function to extract individual elements from the schedule tuple.  For example `regexp_substr(schedule, '[0-9*]+', 1,1)` will extract the minute element, while `regexp_substr(sched, '[0-9*]+', 1, 2)` will extract the hour element.  The 4th parameter selects the desired element.  You can then use either the `EXTRACT` or `TO_CHAR` function to get at various portions of your timestamp for comparison.

```
with cron(ID, Sched) as (
  select 102, '00 9 * * * *' from dual
), exec(id, ts) as (
  select 102, to_timestamp('2017-11-05 9:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  select 102, to_timestamp('2017-11-05 9:05:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual
), c2 as (
select id
     , sched 
     , regexp_substr(sched,'[0-9*]+',1,1) min
     , regexp_substr(sched,'[0-9*]+',1,2) hour
     , regexp_substr(sched,'[0-9*]+',1,3) day
     , regexp_substr(sched,'[0-9*]+',1,4) mon
     , regexp_substr(sched,'[0-9*]+',1,5) wday
     , regexp_substr(sched,'[0-9*]+',1,6) year
  from cron
)
select c2.*
     , exec.ts
     , case when (year = '*' or to_number(to_char(ts,'yyyy')) = to_number(year))
             and (mon  = '*' or to_number(to_char(ts,'mm')  ) = to_number(mon ))
             and (day  = '*' or to_number(to_char(ts,'dd')  ) = to_number(day ))
             and (hour = '*' or to_number(to_char(ts,'hh24')) = to_number(hour))
             and (min  = '*' or to_number(to_char(ts,'mi')  ) = to_number(min ))
             and (wday = '*' or to_number(to_char(ts,'d')   ) = to_number(wday))
            then 'OK'
            else 'KO'
       end Match
  from exec 
  join c2 
    on c2.id = exec.id;
```

move the logical expression from the case statement in part or whole as needed to get the results you need.

Comment: many thanks! I’ll try it tomorrow and I’ll keep you informed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer for Snowflake or Redshift users.

In the general case, answering this question with SQL requires generating timestamps from a cron expression. This is possible in pure (Snowflake or Redshift) SQL, but it requires ~200 lines, so here's a link to [sample code on Github](https://github.com/jaysobel/sql-cron-to-timestamps/blob/main/sql_cron_to_timestamps.sql).

And an outline of how it works.

The expression is split into rows on the space character, noting the time part (1 -> "minutes"), then and then further split by the comma.

Parsing starts by replacing day and month codes with their corresponding numbers, and converting the day number 7 to 0 (both mean Sunday). Asterisks are replaced with the full range of the given time part; "*" for minutes becomes 0-59.

Range values and step size are extracted by splitting the "-" and "/" of each subentry. Range end is imputed with range start (to set up a SQL `between` which is inclusive) and step size is imputed with 1 (to set up a `mod`).

A table of time parts and their possible values is generated, and joined against the broken down expression on the conditions of [time part name, value between between range start/end, mod of step size is 0]. Redundant matches are de-duped.

Then the matches can be cross joined together, and concatenated into timestamps. A year spine is also needed, and can be hard-coded or passed as a parameter.

There's one additional wrinkle with the interaction of day-of-week and day-of-month matches. If either of the parts uses a * (in the first position only, [a bug that is the de facto standard](https://crontab.guru/cron-bug.html)), then days matching either part are included (union / or). If neither uses *, then days must match both parts to be included (intersect / and).

This "day matching mode" is determined before the "*" is replaced. A spine of days within each month are cross joined, and day-of-week matches are left joined, followed by day-of-month matches. The "day matching mode" label is used to determine the matching mode, and presence/absence logic across the two sets of matched days.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).