# SQL: Store and query `cron` field

Tags: sql, postgresql, cron

I'm building a cron-as-a-service, to allow users to input their cron expression, and do some stuff periodically.

Here's a simple version of my table:

```sql
create table users (
  id serial not null primary key,
  -- `text` seems the most straightforward data type, any other suggestions?
  cron text not null,
  constraint valid_cron_expression CHECK (cron ~* '{some_regex}'),
  -- snip --
  -- maybe some other fields, like what to do on each cron call
)
```

My backend runs a SQL query every minute. How can I query all the rows whose `cron` field match the current timestamp (rounded to the closest minute)?

Edit: users input the `cron` field as a [cron expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), e.g. `5 4 * * *`.

Edit 2: corrected the fact that cron time resolution is minute, not second.

Comment: Why is `cron` stored as a string if you want to compare to a date/time value?

Comment: `cron` is a user-inputted cron expression, e.g. `5 4 * * *`. String seems the most straightforward type. I clarified the original post.

Comment: Or you could use [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver as I understand, pg_cron runs cron jobs inside the DB. I can set up a pg_cron to run every second, but how do I query all users whose `cron` field matches the current second?

Comment: `cron` runs every minute so matching to the second is not going to work.  If you want second resolution you will need to roll your own solution. Not sure how you would work around lack of second resolution in cron expressions passed in? There is RRULE from the iCalendar standard it has resolution down to the second,  but that is an entirely different beast

Comment: Correct about second vs minute. I updated my initial question. However, I still don't see how pg_cron can be useful in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't need to query every second because the cron has only a one minute resolution.

Next, comparing a cron scheduler expression to a timestamp is not a trivial task.
I'm not aware of any PostgreSQL module that would be able to parse the cron expressions.

There are two options, either you write your own function to do the comparison, or else you use a external library in the programming language you are using to do the comparison outside of the Database.

Here you will find an example implementation of such a function for Oracle that could easily be ported to PostgreSQL: [SQL Query to convert cron expression to date/time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145777/sql-query-to-convert-cron-expression-to-date-time-format)

It is incomplete because it doesn't handle complex expressions like */5 or 5,10,15 for individual fields of the cron expression but this is where I would start.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I was mistaken about second vs minute, I corrected my initial post. `or else you use a external library in the programming language...`: This requires me to query all rows from the table, and filter in the application logic, right? I'll explore the SO link you posted, thanks.

Comment: Yes, in this case you do the filtering logic on the full table in the application. This seems reasonable as the number of crontab entries shouldn't be huge.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to adjust some functions to mach your SQL dialect, but this seems to work, your only entry here is the value for ETL_CRON and the output is a boolean RUN_ETL.
The example returns TRUE at every 12th minute from 3 through 59 past every hour from 2 through 22 on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday.:

```
select
      '3/12 2-22 * * 1,2,3,4,5'   as etl_cron
    , split_part(etl_cron,' ',1) as etl_minute
    , split_part(etl_cron,' ',2) as etl_hour
    , split_part(etl_cron,' ',3) as etl_daymonth
    , split_part(etl_cron,' ',4) as etl_month
    , split_part(etl_cron,' ',5) as etl_dayweek
    , convert_timezone('Europe/Amsterdam',current_timestamp) as etl_datetime
    , case 
        when etl_minute = '*' then true
        when contains(etl_minute,'-') then minute(etl_datetime) between split_part(etl_minute,'-',1) and split_part(etl_minute,'-',2)
        when contains(etl_minute,'/') then mod(minute(etl_datetime),split_part(etl_minute,'/',2)) - split_part(etl_minute,'/',1) = 0
        else array_contains(minute(etl_datetime)::varchar::variant, split(etl_minute,','))
      end as run_minute
    , case
        when etl_hour = '*' then true
        when contains(etl_hour,'-') then hour(etl_datetime) between split_part(etl_hour,'-',1) and split_part(etl_hour,'-',2) 
        when contains(etl_hour,'/') then mod(hour(etl_datetime),split_part(etl_hour,'/',2)) - split_part(etl_hour,'/',1) = 0
        else array_contains(hour(etl_datetime)::varchar::variant, split(etl_hour,','))
      end as run_hour
    , case 
        when etl_daymonth = '*' then true
        when contains(etl_daymonth,'-') then day(etl_datetime) between split_part(etl_daymonth,'-',1) and split_part(etl_daymonth,'-',2) 
        when contains(etl_daymonth,'/') then mod(day(etl_datetime),split_part(etl_daymonth,'/',2)) - split_part(etl_daymonth,'/',1) = 0
        else array_contains(day(etl_datetime)::varchar::variant, split(etl_daymonth,','))
      end as run_daymonth
    , case 
        when etl_month = '*' then true
        when contains(etl_month,'-') then month(etl_datetime) between split_part(etl_month,'-',1) and split_part(etl_month,'-',2) 
        when contains(etl_month,'/') then mod(month(etl_datetime),split_part(etl_month,'/',2)) - split_part(etl_month,'/',1) = 0
        else array_contains(month(etl_datetime)::varchar::variant, split(etl_month,','))
      end as run_month
    , case 
        when etl_dayweek = '*' then true
        when contains(etl_dayweek,'-') then dayofweek(etl_datetime) between split_part(etl_dayweek,'-',1) and split_part(etl_dayweek,'-',2) 
        when contains(etl_dayweek,'/') then mod(dayofweek(etl_datetime),split_part(etl_dayweek,'/',2)) - split_part(etl_dayweek,'/',1) = 0
        else array_contains(dayofweek(etl_datetime)::varchar::variant, split(etl_dayweek,','))
      end as run_dayweek
    , run_minute and run_hour and run_daymonth and run_month and run_dayweek as run_etl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This addresses the original version of the question.

Assuming that `cron` is a timestamp of some sort, you would use:

```
where cron >= date_trunc('second', now()) and
      cron < date_trun('second', now()) + interval '1 second'
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, `cron` is not a timestamp, but a cron expression, e.g. `5 4 * * *`. I updated my original question.